# Streming Audio Stored in DB - JPlayer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, video-streaming, jplayer

I'm using JPlayer in my website but while trying to implement it, it says that you need to use setMedia to set the tracks (i.e. Have a file type supplied). Here is the code that is given on their website:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
      $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
        m4a: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-07-Bubble.m4a",
        oga: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-07-Bubble.ogg"
      });
    },
    swfPath: "/js",
    supplied: "m4a, oga"
  });
});
```

But, what do you do if you're pulling the tracks from a database and therefore you don't know what the extension type is or what the file name is?

Comment: It's very difficult to make the jplayer works when you do not know the  file type, because the player will be streaming the media according to   it.